# MS SQL Server: How to get the counts of each visit type per date range per user?

Tags: sql-server, join, count, datediff

I have 2 tables.

The first table `Users` contains attributes `id, session, start_date,` and `end_date`. The `id` is an int that uniquely identifies each user. The `session` is an int that keeps track of each continuous date range for each user. `start_date` and `end_date` reflect the date range of each session for each user. Users can show up multiple times in this table, and you may assume that if a user is included multiple times, their next session's `start_date` happens after their previous session's `end_date`.

Here is an example of the `Users` table:

```
| id | session | start_date   | end_date     |
|----|---------|--------------|--------------|
| 1  | 1       | '2017-01-01' | '2017-03-01' |
| 1  | 2       | '2017-04-01' | '2017-10-01' |
| 2  | 1       | '2017-01-01' | '2017-12-31' |
| 3  | 1       | '2017-01-01' | '2017-12-31' |
```

The second table `Visits` contains attributes `id, visit_date,` and `visit_type`. `id` is the same `id` as in the `Users` table. `visit_date` (date) and `visit_type` (string) detail the date of a visit for each user and the type of each visit. Users can show up multiple times in this table or not show up at all.

Here is an example of the `Visits` table:

```
| id | visit_date   | visit_type |
|----|--------------|------------|
| 1  | '2017-01-05' | 'a'        |
| 1  | '2017-02-06' | 'a'        |
| 1  | '2017-04-01' | 'a'        |
| 1  | '2017-05-02' | 'b'        |
| 1  | '2017-06-13' | 'b'        |
| 1  | '2017-01-12' | 'c'        |
| 2  | '2017-04-01' | 'a'        |
| 2  | '2017-12-01' | 'd'        |
```

I need to write a query that returns the number of visits for each `visit_type` for each user's session in the `Users` table where the session was at least 90 days long and the `visit_date` falls within the session range (dates inclusive). If a user's session does not have any visits of a particular type, it is recorded as `visit_type` of NULL and `visit_count` of 0.

Here is the desired output based off of the above tables:

```
-- |id|session|start_date  |end_date    |visit_type|visit_count|
-- |1 |2      |'2017-04-01'|'2017-10-01'|’a’       |1          |
-- |1 |2      |'2017-04-01'|'2017-10-01'|’b’       |2          |
-- |2 |1      |'2017-01-01'|'2017-12-31'|’a’       |1          |
-- |2 |1      |'2017-01-01'|'2017-12-31'|’d’       |1          |
-- |3 |1      |'2017-01-01'|'2017-12-31'|NULL      |0          |
```

```
SELECT Users.id, Users.session, Users.start_date, Users.end_date, 
  Visits.visit_date, Visits.visit_type
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Visits ON Users.id = Visits.id
WHERE (
    DATEDIFF(DAY, Users.start_date, Users.end_date) >= 90
  )
ORDER BY Users.id, Users.session
;
```

From this code, I expected an output where for each user and session the `visit_date` and `visit_type` were recorded. The only sessions included would be those that were 90 days or longer.

However, I'm running into an error using the `DATEDIFF` function where it says my parameters are incorrect.

How can I use `DATEDIFF` to filter out the sessions shorter than 90 days in length?

Comment: which database system are you using, every has its own function

Comment: Regarding the tag "SQL" if you hover over that tag please read its description: "*Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL*"

Answer (score 0):

This may simply be a matter of using `day` instead of `DAY` in the datediff function, but also you seem to need a a group by to achieve the visit count:

```
SELECT
      Users.id
    , Users.session
    , Users.start_date
    , Users.end_date
    , Visits.visit_type
    , COUNT(Visits.visit_type) AS visit_count
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Visits ON Users.id = Visits.id
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, Users.start_date, Users.end_date) >= 90
    AND Visits.visit_date BETWEEN Users.start_date AND Users.end_date
GROUP BY
      Users.id
    , Users.session
    , Users.start_date
    , Users.end_date
    , Visits.visit_type
ORDER BY
      Users.id
    , Users.session
```

see: [TSQL datediff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

**nb** this assumes you are using SQL Server. If this is incorrect please choose the correct dbms as a tag under your question. Also note that "sql" is NOT an alias for "sql server".